# LibGDX для android. Как перевести координаты спрайта в координаты текстуры?

Tags: libgdx, java, android

Мне надо понять логику систем координат. У меня есть объекты-машинки. Я вывожу их на экран как СПРАЙТЫ. Иначе нельзя, потому что только спрайты можно поворачивать. Поле (стадион) я рисую как текстуру (то есть НЕ КАК СПРАЙТ). Иначе нельзя, потому что только текстуры можно прокручивать по экрану (спрайты не умеют прокручиваться). Так вот, выяснилось, что текстуры и спрайты выводятся в разных координатах! Как перевести координаты спрайта в координаты текстуры?

```
//Координаты экрана 
m_screenRectangle.set(0, 0, m_camera.viewportWidth, m_camera.viewportHeight);

//Загружаю текстуру стадиона из файла
m_roadTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("road_map.png"));

// Создаю регион 
m_myRoadTexture = new TextureRegion(
m_roadTexture, 
(int)m_roadRectangle.x, (int)m_roadRectangle.y,
(int)m_roadRectangle.width, (int)m_roadRectangle.height
)

//Устанавливаю окно просмотра стадиона
m_myRoadTexture.setRegion(
(int)m_roadRectangle.x, (int)m_roadRectangle.y,
(int)m_roadRectangle.width, (int)m_roadRectangle.height
)

//Вывожу на экран текстуру стадиона

batch.draw(m_myRoadTexture, m_screenRectangle.x, m_screenRectangle.y, m_screenRectangle.width, m_screenRectangle.height);

//ТЕПЕРЬ ХОЧУ НАРИСОВАТЬ НА ПОВЕРХНОСТИ СТАДИОНА МОЙ СПРАЙТ

//Подготавливаю мой спрайт для отображения:
MY_SPRITE.setBounds(MY_SPRITE_x, MY_SPRITE_y, MY_SPRITE_width, MY_SPRITE_height);
MY_SPRITE.setOriginCenter();
//Отображаю на поверхности стадиона отобразить спрайт
MY_SPRITE.draw(batch);
```

В результете вижу: 
СПРАЙТ отобразился на поверхности стадиона, но НЕ В ТОМ МЕСТЕ, где надо!
При этом, на разных устройствах, позиция спрайта разная!

ВОПРОС: Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Текстуры тоже можно поворачивать при отрисовке http://goo.gl/x9kZmh

Answer (score 1):

Получите координаты XY стадиона.
Теперь на основании их вы можете манипулировать вашими машинками
Например

```
float stX = stadion.getX();//координата стадиона по Х
float stY = stadion.getY();//координата стадиона по У
car.setPosition(stX + 128, stY + 128);// машинка отобразится на стадионе в указанной позиции
```

Лучше всего используйте разрешения самого устройства (ширину , высоту) для точных подсчетов и масштабирования независимо от устройства.

```
float stX = stadion.getX();
float stY = stadion.getY();
car.setPosition(stX + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/32, stY + Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/32)
```